# flutter Change part of text selected color in textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

I want when the user selects a part of the text in textfield and clicks on the color button, only that part of the selected text will be colored.
Thanks

I searched all the articles but couldn't find any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nima jan Salaam,
you need to use [rich_text_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_text_controller/install) package like this code below:

1. first of all add `rich_text_controller: ^1.4.0` in your `pubspec.yaml` (or any compatible versions).
2. 

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rich_text_controller/rich_text_controller.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: RichTextControllerDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class RichTextControllerDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const RichTextControllerDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<RichTextControllerDemo> createState() => _RichTextControllerDemoState();
}

class _RichTextControllerDemoState extends State<RichTextControllerDemo> {

  RichTextController? _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {

    _controller = RichTextController(


      stringMatchMap: {
        "test": const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      },

      onMatch: (List<String> matches){

      }

    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                
                onChanged: (value){
                },
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top : 20.0),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: const Text('click'),
                  onTap: (){

                  var start = _controller!.selection.start;
                  var end  = _controller!.selection.end;
                  var text = _controller!.text.substring(start,end);
                    setState(() {
                      _controller!.stringMatchMap!.addAll(
                        {
                          text : const TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan),
                        }
                      );
                    });
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

happy coding bro...